# shareLaTex image not showing up

Tags: graphics

I'm using one of the preset project formats provided by Sharelatex (thesis template with memoir). The .tex file looks like:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} %I've tried removing [dvips] here but this doesn't make a difference?
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage[
breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,% PRINT
bookmarks=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},left=25mm,right=25mm, bindingoffset=0mm, top=25mm,bottom=25mm}
\OnehalfSpacing

%%% CHAPTER'S STYLE
\chapterstyle{bianchi}
%%% STYLE OF SECTIONS, SUBSECTIONS, AND SUBSUBSECTIONS
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}

%%% STYLE OF PAGES NUMBERING
\pagestyle{plain}
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{}

\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
\maxtocdepth{subsection} 

\begin{document}
```

Then, later on in my script I use:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{Xray}
\centering
\end{figure}
```

But this doesn't produce a picture, just a box where the picture should be with "Xray.png" in it. I have the .png file in the same folder as the .tex file so I am a little lost as to what could be the problem. Anyone who knows what could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). You need to include the image extension: `.jpg`, `.png`. E.g.: `Xray.jpg`

Comment: Remove option `[dvips]` from `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}`

Comment: @Cragfelt why would anyone need to include the extension?

Comment: you have specified `[dvips]` but dvips can not include png files. If you use pdflatex rather than latex/dvips then it will work.

Comment: it will sort of work by accident but it is much better to put `\centering` at the start of the figure, not the end.

Answer (score 1):

Remove option `[dvips]` from `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` in preamble. As @DavidCarlisle stated, place `\centering` command before the figure command line.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{Xray}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi Cragfelt,
I've removed dvips and tried using .png , .jpeg  and .pdf as format, but all of those won't show me an image still (also I placed the \centering command to before the figure command line like you said). Also I am using pdfLatex as a compiler. Any idea what else could be the cause of the problem? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Kroepoek Well, in that case, it would be better if you show us your work by including a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your original question so we can compile it and find the actual issue you are having.

Comment: @Kroepoek any news about this?